# JavaScript template literals substitute variable later (before values are known)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use template literals somehow before the values a known. Every demo on JS template literals looks like this:

```
var name = "John";
var s = `Hello ${name}`;
```

But in real world, templates are defined before we know variable values. Somewhere is defined template (on page load):

```
var s = `Hello ${name}`;
```

And then, 5 minutes later, when user logs in I want to use this template but it was already substituted so how to actually do it? Similar issue would be how to use template multiple times.

I can imagine having it some wrapper function but I want to have templates in JSON where there cannot be functions. Is it even possible?

Comment: Don't use backticks, just use quotes so it's a normal string; there's your template. Later, when you need to replace values, use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to insert correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Template strings are for populating at the time the template string is declared.

If you want to define it early and populate it later, define it inside a function. (An option you've rejected).

You might consider another template engine such as [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) or [EJS](https://ejs.co/) … but they'll still effectively be wrapped in a function.

Comment: "An option you've rejected" outta pocket, lmao. It is a great alternative for the language model though

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for answering this question an entire year after it was posted.

I ran into the same issue (albeit in another way), and created a function/package to solve it:

https://github.com/OlaHulleberg/varEx

I've intentionally made the syntax similar, but not identical to literal tags, anyways here's **how to use it:**

```js
varEx("Any string you want plus a $[variable] block", objectToResolveFrom);
```

And here's an example:

```js
// Include varEx
const { varEx } = require('varex');

// This is the object we use to resolve variables
const object = {
    var1: "Example",
    var2: "Yet another one",
    var3: "You can even include [] brackets here, even $[variable blocks] doesn't break this",
    varObj: {
        var1: "Supports nesting as well!",
        varArray: [
            "Need arrays? Have at it!"
        ]
    }
};

// Output the result
console.log(
    varEx("This is an $[var1], and here is $[var2]. $[var3]. $[varObj.var1] $[varObj.varArray[0]]", object)
);
```

Please feel free to contribute, and give me feedback if you have any! :)

Comment: Don't be sorry! Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for answering this old question, hope it helps someone else in the future!